# Creación de reportes "pdf" en una aplicación de n-capas .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, crystal-reports, model-view-controller

¿Cómo puedo crear archivos `PDF` para poderlos descargar en la capa de presentación del cliente?

Mi aplicación esta desarrollado en `Asp .Net C#`, utilizo la estructura de `n-capas`, y mi conexión a base de datos esta en la `capa de Datos`, he querido utilizar `Crystal Report`, pero como saben, se necesita de una conexión a base de datos, y en la presentación de cliente no utilizo ni un modelo, solo manda a llamar las vistas, sobre los datos solo mando a llamar `APIs` que ya trae todos los datos y por medio de `JavaScript` manipulo los datos para mostrarlos al cliente.

¿Alguna recomendación?
Pensaba enviar un `array` de datos a mi `controller` y este se haga con la tarea de dibujar el `PDF` y retornarlo de vuelta o utilizar `javascript` para crear `PDF`, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>>he querido utilizar Crystal Report, pero como saben, se necesita de una conexión a base de datos,**

No necesitas ninguna conexion para asignar datos a Crystal, podrias asignarle un Dataset tipado o una List<> con una clase que definas:

[How to Generate Crystal Report Using Custom Object Collection with ASP.NET](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/558_How_to_Generate_Crystal_Report_Using_Custom_Object_Collection_with_ASP_NET.aspx)

como observaras en el articulo cuando asigna el `SetDataSource()` lo hace con una `List<>` de una clase, o sea totalmente desconectado de la `base de datos`

**>>Pensaba enviar un array de datos a mi controller y este se haga con la tarea de dibujar el PDF**

Si es un pdf podrias usar librerias como ser [iTextSharp](http://desarrolladores.me/2014/01/c-creando-archivos-pdf-con-itextsharp/), pero creas el pdf en el servidor y lo envias para su descarga al cliente

**>>utilizar javascript para crear PDF**

No puedes crear un documento desde javascript, esto seria codigo cliente que ejecuta en el browser, por temas de seguridad no puedes crear archivos en la pc del usuario.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos, utilizare entonces iTextSharp.